# Missing Field Exception Unity3d Script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

When I compile my game in debug mode in Unity3D it instantly pauses a quick glance at the console reveals the following error:

> MissingFieldException: UnityEngine.Light.Enable

Here is the script it is very simply meant to make the point light flicker when the randomiser is below 0.7.

```c#
var FlashingLight : Light;
FlashingLight.enabled = false;

function FixedUpdate (){

    var RandomNumber = Random.value;
        if(RandomNumber<=.7){

            FlashingLight.enable = true;

        }

        else FlashingLight.enabled=false;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Change `FlashingLight.enable = true;` to `FlashingLight.enabled = true;`, it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The field is called [`enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Light.html), not `enable`.